# Creating application menu entry from installation script

Tags: ubuntu, installation, menu

I'm trying to create an install.sh for an app I want to distribute. I created a .desktop entry for the app, and it is copied into /usr/share/applications/ during installation.(In Ubuntu 9.10)

The entry appears in the menu after installation and is accessible. But after I logout and login again, the menu entry disappears. The .desktop file is still in the applications directory, and renaming it makes the entry reappear. What additional change should I make to install.sh to avoid the entry from disappearing?

I made a .DEB package using the same .desktop file and it doesn't have this problem. So I guess I'm missing some step in the install.sh. For now, it copies the binaries to a directory in user's home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/desktop-file-install.8.html